# Howto initialize a variable of type StorageFolder with individual path?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am trying to get all the files properties, that the Windows Explorer properties / details Tab shows on my Windows 10 Desktop.

I am following the samples from that article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-getting-file-properties

I have seen that there are functions to get basic and extended file properties.

The basic sample code looks like this:

```
var folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
var query = folder.CreateFileQuery();
var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();

foreach (Windows.Storage.StorageFile file in files)
{
    StringBuilder fileProperties = new StringBuilder();

    // Get top-level file properties.
    fileProperties.AppendLine("File name: " + file.Name);
    fileProperties.AppendLine("File type: " + file.FileType);
}
```

I have managed to find out required additional steps to make it work like implementation of async method and adjust settings to access picture library. It works.

Now I would like to change the code in a way that it does not run for the **Picture Library** but instead in any folder I would like to hardcode in a first step and make selectable by users in a second step.

Unfortunately I fail. How do I have to adjust the code to make it use a path like "c:\test" ?

The **query** method of the code uses a **StorageFolder** object.

What I tried:

The "good old"

```
var di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\test");
```

does not create a type that seems somehow compatible with a StorageFolder. This does not work:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder f = (StorageFolder)di;
```

That does not work either:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder f = new StorageFolder();
```

Then I found this working option:

```
var folder1 = Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("c:\test");
```

But then the `folder.CreateFileQuery()` method is not happy with it and denies to work.

Next try after reading suggested similar questions:

```
try
{
    folder = await folder.GetFolderAsync(folderName);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    await folder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName);
}
```

Leads into this exception:

> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057   Nachricht = Value does
>   not fall within the expected range.   Quelle = System.Private.CoreLib

I am sure this is an easy task, but I can't find a solution to make the samples work with a specific folder on my hard disk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > How do I have to adjust the code to make it use a path like "c:\test"

If you want to access the folder in full path, first you need to add [broadFileSystemAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example) capability in your manifest and then access is configurable in **Settings** > **Privacy** > **File system** to **allow** your app to access file system. After that, you can pass the folder path to `GetFolderFromPathAsync` method to get the specified folder.

```
var folder1 = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"c:\test");
var query = folder1.CreateFileQuery();
var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();

foreach (Windows.Storage.StorageFile file in files)
{
    StringBuilder fileProperties = new StringBuilder();

    // Get top-level file properties.
    fileProperties.AppendLine("File name: " + file.Name);
    fileProperties.AppendLine("File type: " + file.FileType);
}
```

Comment: I have added this to the manifest: 
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" and <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" /> to the Capabilities part. This brings up a looong error message. Also I cannot find SETTINGS. Where is this? TY

Comment: Do you mean there is a green wavy line under rescap:Capability? If it is, you can ignore this issue, it has no influence. You can choose "settings" app in your start menu or search "settings", and click it, then found Privacy and File system. Under the "Choose which apps can access your file system" tab to allow your app to access file system.